# trouble getting Lapply with on-the-fly function to run correctly

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am trying to work with lapply function using a dataframe based on a binary variable in the 5th column.

The function I made is pretty straight forward. a simple t.test and works quite well

```
t.test.by.ind = function(x, ind) {
  stopifnot(all(ind %in% c(0, 1)))
  return(t.test(x[ind == 0], x[ind == 1]))
}
```

now, to the problem, I cannot for the life of me get lapply working. I've tried several variants such as:

```
##Note that pros.dat = my dataframe

lapply(pros.dat, FUN = function(df){
  return(apply(pros.dat[,-5], MARGIN = 2, 
      FUN = t.test.by.ind, ind = pros.dat[,5]))
})
```

and

```
##Note that pros.dat = my dataframe

lapply(pros.dat, FUN = function(df){
  return(apply(df[,-5], MARGIN = 2, 
      FUN = t.test.by.ind, ind = df[,5]))
})
```

I have the worst time trying to get lapply to work. I can get apply working just fine.

```
apply(pros.dat[,-5], MARGIN = 2, FUN = t.test.by.ind, ind = pros.dat[,5])
```

Why can't I see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: IIn the `lapply`, where are you using `df`  YOu may need `lapply(pro.dat[-5], function(df) t.test.by.ind(df, ind = pros.dat[,5]))`

Comment: This worked well. Thank you very much as always akrun!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you lapply through a data.frame, you are iterating through its columns, so you just apply something similar to what you have in apply, without the margin argument:

```
pros.dat = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100*4),ncol=4),ind=rbinom(100,1,0.5))
lapply(pros.dat[,-5],function(i)t.test.by.ind(i,pros.dat[,5]))
```

Comment: The comment is very helpful. thank you. The function syntax FUN = function(df) and arguments was the game changer.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` needs a vector as its argument.
So you could use the indexes of the columns of `pros.dat` that you want to analyse:

```
my_columns=c(1,2,3,4) # for instance
lapply(my_columns,function(col) t.test.by.ind(x=pros.dat[,col],y=pros.dat[5]))
```

Comment: wolf beat you by a few minutes. Thank you so much though. I see now that the function (arg1, arg2) is were I was messing up.